# Editing JSON from RecyclerView AdapterClass

Tags: json, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to edit my JSON in Assets, by using the Buttons of a RecyclerView, does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried making a `jsonObject` in the `Adapterclass` which doesn't work because the `.open()` doesn't work in adapter classes.
I also tried accessing my existing `jsonObj` in my `Mainfile` which doesn't work either.

```
package com.example.wanderapp.ui.stempel

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.wanderapp.R
import com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
import org.json.JSONArray
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStream

class

MyAdapter(val slist: ArrayList<StempelModelClass>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.list_item,
        parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return slist.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = slist[position]
        holder.tvHeading.text = currentItem.name
        holder.add.setOnClickListener {
            holder.add.setText("Added")
            //here i want to edit my JSON
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val titleImage: ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_image)
        val tvHeading: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading)
        val add: Button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.AddBtn)
    }

}
```